# How to Change the Lockscreen image in windows 10 using python?

Tags: python, windows, lockscreen

I have changed the desktop wallpaper using `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20,0,wallpaper_image,0)`

Like wise to change lockscreen image using python.

Answer (score -1):

1. Extract `igcmdWin10.exe` from the [ImageGlass ".Zip" release from the github repository](https://github.com/d2phap/ImageGlass/releases).
2. Put it in the same folder as your python script

Insert this code:

```py
import os

src = r"C:\image-file.jpg"
os.system(f'igcmdWin10.exe setlockimage {src}')
```

The official documentation for reference: [ImageGlass: Command line utilities](https://imageglass.org/docs/command-line-utilities)